# Add a Widget (QProgressbar) as a childItem within a QTreeView

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2, qtreeview, qprogressbar

I made a model that adds data to a QTreeView. I want to add a widget (eg: QProgressbar) as a child element to each row within that QTreeView. So that every time if we click on each row we can see the progressbar as a childItem for that row

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHeaderView, QPushButton
from PySide2 import QtCore
from TreeViewUI import Ui_MainWindow
from custom_models.table_model import CustomTableModel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.table_model = CustomTableModel(data)
        self.treeView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(360 / 4, 640 / 4))
        self.treeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.table_model)

def get_data():
    content_list = [
        {
            "user_id": 101,
            "user_name": "User_1",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_1",
            "user_progress": 45,

        },
        {
            "user_id": 102,
            "user_name": "User_2",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_2",
            "user_progress": 33,

        },
        {
            "user_id": 103,
            "user_name": "User_3",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_3",
            "user_progress": 80,

        },



    ]
    return content_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    data = get_data()
    main_window = MainWindow(data)
    main_window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**table_model.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QImage, QIcon, QPixmap

class CustomTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.content_id = []
        self.content_names = []
        self.content_url = []
        self.content_variant = []
        self.content_progress = []
        for content_data in data:
            self.content_id.append(content_data["user_id"])
            self.content_names.append(content_data["user_name"])
            self.content_url.append(content_data["user_image"])
            self.content_variant.append(content_data["user_details"])
            self.content_progress.append(content_data["user_progress"])

        self.row_count = len(self.content_id)
        self.column_count = 4

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.column_count


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return ("ID", "NAME", "IMAGE PREVIEW", "DETAILS")[section]


    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                content_id = self.content_id[row]
                return content_id
            elif column == 1:
                return self.content_names[row]
            elif column == 3:
                return self.content_variant[row]




        elif role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            if column == 2:
                image_path = self.content_url[row]
                image = QImage()
                image.load(image_path)
                icon = QIcon()
                icon.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
                return icon


        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignLeft
```

**TreeViewUI.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(817, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.treeView = QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setObjectName(u"treeView")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)


        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"TreeView", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

These are the files I created to test for a sample implementation for QTreeView.
The basic structure of the Treeview would be as follows:

```
User_ID  User_Name  User_Image  User_Details
101       ABC       abc.jpg      abc
 QProgressBar widget for the above user(101)# QProgressbar as the childItem for each row.
102       DEF       def.jpg      def
 QProgressBar widget for the above user(102)
103       GHI       ghi.png      ghi
 QProgressBar widget for the above user(103)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "child element to each row", could you place an image of what you want to get since what you say is unclear?

Comment: I am trying to add a QProgressbar as a childItem for each user. So as a user clicks on a row a child row should appear below it that will contain a progressbar

Comment: I do not understand what a *child row* is for you so I ask you for an image or scheme of what you want

Comment: I have updated the question with the structure I am lookig for the QProgressbar as the childItem for each row. Can you please have a look at it

Comment: Okay, I understand what you want, one last question, what would be the width of the QProgressBar?

Comment: It can be 100 as I want to display the amount of work done by each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structure is of tree type then the model must have that structure so that model based on QAbstractItemModel could be used but to make it simpler I have implemented it using the QStandardItemModel class where I have established the values in the appropriate roles, and so that the progressbar It is displayed in a new file so you must be a child of the item. To show the progressbar I have not set a widget but it has been painted using the QStyle through a delegate:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel


class UserModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UserModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(4)

    def appendUser(self, id_, name, image, details, progress):
        items = []
        row = self.rowCount()
        for text, column in zip((id_, name, details), (0, 1, 3)):
            it = QStandardItem()
            it.setData(text, Qt.DisplayRole)
            self.setItem(row, column, it)
            items.append(it)
        image_item = QStandardItem()
        image_item.setData(QIcon(image), Qt.DecorationRole)
        self.setItem(row, 2, image_item)
        progress_item = QStandardItem()
        progress_item.setData(progress, Qt.UserRole)
        items[0].appendRow(progress_item)
```

```py
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QHeaderView,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QStyleOptionProgressBar,
    QStyle,
)

from TreeViewUI import Ui_MainWindow
from custom_models.table_model import UserModel

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class ProgressDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.parent().isValid():
            r = option.rect
            r.setWidth(200)
            progress = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
            progress_option = QStyleOptionProgressBar()
            progress_option.rect = r
            progress_option.minimum = 0
            progress_option.maximum = 100
            progress_option.progress = progress
            progress_option.text = "{}%".format(progress)
            progress_option.textVisible = True
            QApplication.style().drawControl(
                QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, progress_option, painter
            )
            return
        super(ProgressDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = UserModel(self)
        for content_data in data:
            self.model.appendUser(
                content_data["user_id"],
                content_data["user_name"],
                os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, content_data["user_image"]),
                content_data["user_details"],
                content_data["user_progress"],
            )
        self.treeView.setIconSize(QSize(360 / 4, 640 / 4))
        self.treeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        delegate = ProgressDelegate(self.treeView)
        self.treeView.setItemDelegate(delegate)


def get_data():
    content_list = [
        {
            "user_id": 101,
            "user_name": "User_1",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_1",
            "user_progress": 45,
        },
        {
            "user_id": 102,
            "user_name": "User_2",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_2",
            "user_progress": 33,
        },
        {
            "user_id": 103,
            "user_name": "User_3",
            "user_image": "images/demo.jpg",
            "user_details": "details_3",
            "user_progress": 80,
        },
    ]
    return content_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    data = get_data()
    main_window = MainWindow(data)
    main_window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Another possible solution is to create a persistent editor through the delegate:

```py
class ProgressDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.parent().isValid():
            view = option.widget
            if isinstance(view, QTreeView) and index.model() is view.model():
                view.openPersistentEditor(index)
            return
        super(ProgressDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.parent().isValid():
            editor = QProgressBar(parent)
            editor.setFixedWidth(200)
            editor.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            editor.setValue(index.data(Qt.UserRole))
            return editor
        super(ProgressDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
```

**Nota:** Painting a QProgressBar as I did in the first delegate is a trivial task but if you want to place more complex widgets (widgets that have more states like QPushButton) then it is better to use the second option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I also add other widgets using the same process?

Comment: @PratikTayshete Read my update, test and experiment. You must be more precise in your comments since saying: *Can I also add other widgets* can be interpreted by adding more widgets next to the QProgressbar or using another widget instead of QProgressBar, for example a QPushButton. In the first case you can use my second delegate and place a unique widget as a container and set the widgets through a layout. In the second case, just use my second option.